# One-line frequency dictionary in Python

Tags: python

Given an iterable (like a string or list or something), is there a clean, *O*(n) way to make a dictionary that maps elements to their frequency using 1 line? I don't want to use any external libraries or modules

The code should have the same functionality as the following snippet:

```py
s = 'abcaba'
freq = {}
for i in s:
  if i not in freq:
    freq[i] = 1
  else:
    freq[i] += 1

### and now, freq = {'a':3, 'b':2, 'c':1}
```

This is *O*(n), but it's a couple of lines. I can also do this:

```py
s = 'abcaba'
freq = {i: s.count(i) for i in s}

### same thing, now freq = {'a':3, 'b':2, 'c':1}
```

This is 1 line, but it's *O*(n<sup>2</sup>), since `count` is *O*(n) and you also have a loop.

There's probably an easy solution to this that I'm not thinking of. I apologize if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

```
In [212]: s = 'abcaba'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        

In [213]: collections.Counter(s)
Out[213]: Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1})
```

Here's another approach (though not exactly a one-liner):

```
In [214]: freq = {}

In [215]: for char in s: freq[char] = freq.get(char, 0)+1

In [216]: freq
Out[216]: {'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> freq = Counter('abcab')
>>> freq['a']
2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from collections import Counter

result = Counter("123245")

print(result)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'2': 2, '1': 1, '3': 1, '4': 1, '5': 1})
```

You can also use:

```
dict(result)
# {'1': 1, '2': 2, '3': 1, '4': 1, '5': 1}
```